# Find a record in db with a range of OffsetDateTime in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a date column in my postgres database and I want to be able to find a record with a given date range.

For example, in my database i have a record with `2018-10-29 09:05:30.100` `updatetime` column. I want to find this record with a OffsetDateTime +- 5 seconds.

How do I fix it in my Java code to tell db to get me a record between `2018-10-29 09:05:25.100` and `2018-10-29 09:05:35.100`? (There can only be 1 record in that range, so don't worry about the outcome.)

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This is a possible solution to my problem I come up with but I'm not sure if there is a way to do that. I seach it but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: Have you tried just using `where yourdatecolumn between ? and ?` and setting the offsetdatetimes? See also: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/java8-date-time.html

Comment: What is the *exact* data type of the column? Is it `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, or `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`?

Comment: You talk about using `OffsetDateTime`, but your example data lacks an offset-from-UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class you must be interested in moments, actual points on the timeline. If so, your database column should be of data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (*not* `WITHOUT`).

But strangely, your example data lacks the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), a number of hours-minutes-seconds. You must specify either an offset or a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) (`ZoneId` & `ZonedDateTime`) to determine a moment.

I will adjust your input string by assigning an arbitrary offset.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-10-29T09:05:30.100+02:00" );
```

Adjust for your ±5 seconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ) ;
OffsetDateTime start = odt.minus( d ) ;
OffsetDateTime stop = odt.plus( d ) ;
```

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

Here we use the common Half-Open approach to defining a span of time. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Notice that we do *not* use the SQL command `BETWEEN`.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE when >= ? AND when < ? ;" ;
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
pstmt.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
pstmt.setObject( 2 , stop ) ;
```

Retrieving values.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
String sqlQuery = "select * from table_name where updatetime <= '" 
           + yourDatetime.toString() +
           "'::timestamp with time zone + interval '5 second' and updatetime >= '" + 
           + yourDatetime.toString() + "'::timestamp with time zone - interval '5 second'";
```

but you should format `yourDatetime` variable as

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

> Side note: You can mold `sqlQuery` accordingly to make your prepared statement.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).